# Symfony project "homepage" after authenticating?

Tags: php, symfony

I have to make modifications on a Symfony project and I am looking where it is defined that a certain page shows up after authenticating. The user logs with a ldap security that is defined in the security yml file, but I can't find anywhere where the homepage is listed. I know if a user wants to access a certain page and is not authenticated, he will login and then be redirected to this page, but my question is if he passes though the login page first.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to configure where to redirect the user after a successful login?

Comment: This is already done in the project, but I need to know where it is done. The user is redirected to /list, but I can't find anywhere where this is coded.

Comment: Check the default_target_path option in your app/config/security.yml file for the firewall

Comment: Actually, it redirects to just /, but I still want to know where this is specified, or is it the default behaviour?

Comment: I don't have any default_target_path in my security file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is set in the security.yml file under the default_target_path option for the firewall being used. The default value for this is just / which is the behaviour you're getting. See the docs for all default security.yml options: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html

If you want to set a different login success route you just add the path here. You can also combine this with the always_use_default_target_path option to send the user here after login, regardless of which URL they tried visit before authentication.